# sometime mysql disconnected, due to increase load visitor

Tags: mysql, performance, remote-access

Its only disconnected for one second, If I reload the page its connected.

This my default config code from mysql

which number should I increase for mysql,

Which can load heavily

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
[client]
    port=3306
    socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
#bind-address = 123.123.123.8
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

symbolic-links=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
thread_concurrency = 8

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table

max_connections=800
max_user_connections=50
wait_timeout=2000
interactive_timeout=2000
long_query_time=5

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

**/var/log/mysql/error.log**

```
171217 19:58:58 [Warning] IP address '58.218.200.24' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
171217 21:04:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

171217 21:04:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
171217 21:04:29 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 139280  user: 'admin_x'

171217 21:04:29 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 139279  user: 'admin_x'
```

Operating System (OS/VERSION):
Debian 8.9 (x86_64)

Control Panel: Vestacp

Thanks all of you

Comment: Let's see the log file, some clue of what was going on when it happened, digest of the slowlog, client layer, database size, MyISAM vs InnoDB, and any other clues you might come up with.

Comment: Hi @rick-james I just found some error in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` in question updated

Comment: Give this a try:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html

Comment: @rick-james in this file i have to add `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in the directory `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`,
Name it `mirta.cnf`.
Have 2 lines in it:

```
[mysqld]
host-cache-size = 600
```

[*Reference*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_host_cache_size)

Comment: Added should I restart

Comment: after changes, mysql restart failed